# clases hashtable y hashMap ayuda!

Tags: java, netbeans, estructuras-de-datos, hashmap

Debo implementar un sistema para la visualización y actualización de datos de estudiantes. Al inicio el sistema debe cargar los datos del archivo estudiantes.txt y mostrar el siguiente menú:

1. Ver datos
2. Buscar Estudiante
3. Salir

¿Para realizar este proyecto qué es más recomendable usar: `Hashtable` o `HashMap`?

Comment: Algo me dice que el usuario [John](http://es.stackoverflow.com/users/12525/john) y tú están en la misma clase o tienen la misma asignación. Esto lo noto porque él también publicó una pregunta similar: [¿Cuál es mejor: hashtable o hashmap?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/q/19835/227)

Answer (score 1):

Depende de varios factores, necesitas que los objetos estén sincronizados? No permitirás valores en null? Te da igual el orden?

Por lo que comentas, es una aplicación sencilla, te recomiendo entonces que uses [HashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html). Será más rápida y no creo que necesites tantas propiedades como las que tienes el `HashTable`, de todas maneras te dejo un link dónde explica muy bien el funcionamiento del `HashTable` https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html

Comment: La pregunta está orientada a Java, no a .Net.