# ¿Cuál es mejor: hashtable o hashmap?

Tags: java, hashmap

En mi código debo visualizar y buscar datos de un archivo .txt (atributo1|atributo2|atributo3|atributo4), conceptualmente serían idénticos pero para este ejemplo alguno es mejor que otro?

Comment: No señores, la pregunta **no es demasiado amplia**. Por si no lo saben, existe una versión en inglés de esta pregunta y **no está cerrada**: [Differences between HashMap and Hashtable?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/40471/1065197). Por favor dejar de votar como *demasiado amplia* preguntas de las que no conocen o que si conocen creen que requiere una explicación demasiado extensa.

Comment: Si te parece que hay una respuesta que resuelve tu problema, por favor [acéptala](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/a/428/227)

Answer (score 2):

## Versión corta

Para desarrollos nuevos que tú controlas, si tu objeto se va a utilizar en ambientes de un solo hilo o solo es para consultar elementos y nunca registrar/actualizar, es preferible usar `HashMap` sobre `Hashtable`. Si tu objeto se va a utilizar en ambiente multi hilo para soportar múltiples operaciones de actualización, es preferible usar `ConcurrentHashMap` sobre `Hashtable`.

Para tu problema, utiliza `HashMap`.

## Versión extendida

Tu pregunta se reduce entre las diferencias entre [`Hashtable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html) y [`HashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html). Ambas clases implementan la interfaz [`Map`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) y funcionan de manera muy similar puesto que utilizan los métodos `equals` y `hashCode` de la clase llave para obtener la ubicación del objeto del valor en su estructura de datos interna.

La gran diferencia entre ambas clases es que los métodos de `Hashtable` están todas sincronizadas mientras que las operaciones de `HashMap` no lo están. Los métodos de `Hashtable`, al ser sincronizados, tienen un golpe de rendimiento en cada llamada puesto que internamente la JVM debe utilizar un mecanismo de bloqueo para la sincronización de la operación en la ejecución del hilo o hilos donde se comparte la instancia de `Hashtable`. `HashMap`, por el contrario, no sufre de este golpe de rendimiento puesto que sus operaciones no son sincronizadas. Cabe resaltar que `HashMap` no es una clase que se deba utilizar para operaciones en ambiente multi hilos, pero `Hashtable` **tampoco**. Tal como se recomienda en la misma documentación de `Hashtable`, es mejor utilizar [`ConcurrentHashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html):

> As of the Java 2 platform v1.2, this class was retrofitted to implement the Map interface, making it a member of the Java Collections Framework. Unlike the new collection implementations, `Hashtable` is synchronized. If a thread-safe implementation is not needed, it is recommended to use `HashMap` in place of `Hashtable`. If a thread-safe highly-concurrent implementation is desired, then it is recommended to use `ConcurrentHashMap` in place of `Hashtable`

Traducido:

> En la plataforma Java 2 v1.2, esta clase fue agregada para implementar la interfaz `Map`, haciéndola un miembro del Framework de Colecciones de Java. A diferencia de las nuevas implementaciones de colecciones, `Hashtable` es sincronizada. Si no se necesita una implementación segura para hilos, se recomienda usar `HashMap` en lugar de `Hashtable`. Si se desea una implementación segura para hilos que soporte alta concurrencia, entonces se recomienda usar `ConcurrentHashMap` en lugar de `Hashtable`.

Entonces queda la pregunta: ¿cuándo usar `Hashtable`? ¿Es necesaria la existencia de esta clase? La respuesta sería que la clase existe por un tema de compatibilidad con sistemas legados escritos en Java 1.2, 1.3 o 1.4 donde la alternativa era usar `Hashtable`, si la JVM removiese esta clase entonces actualizar la JVM para dichos sistemas ocasionaría muchos problemas y sería necesario actualizar el código, dependiendo de los lugares donde se utilice esta clase, asumiendo que en las librerías externas al proyecto no se utiliza (de todas maneras el cambio de JVM en un sistema siempre trae consigo efectos secundarios, este sería solo uno de ellos). Para desarrollos nuevos, conviene más utilizar la clase `HashMap` o `ConcurrentHashMap`, de acuerdo a tus necesidades.

Para tu problema, utiliza `HashMap`.

Comment: Faltaría agregar una conclusión: no conviene usar `HashTable`  prácticamente nunca.

Comment: Discutible eso de nunca usar HashTable...

Comment: @leonbloy en realidad la respuesta es **depende**, como todo en este mundo del software. La he actualizado para reflejar esta dependencia.

Comment: Dije "prácticamente" nunca, y creo que es lo correcto. Hashtable (en la práctica) es sólo aceptable para codigo "legacy".

Comment: @leonbloy sí, yo lo entiendo, pero muchos lectores obvian el "prácticamente", por ello amplié la respuesta :)